# io.StringIO overwriting an inherited property - to do or not to do?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I subclassed from StringIO to create a MockFile-class. There should be an Attribute "`name`" in the derived class, but creating this Attribute throws an `AttributeError`.

Puzzled i did a `__dict__` lookup and found that there was already a `name`-key. Iterating through the `__mro__` i found a property named '`name`', obviously read-only in the`io.TextIOWrapper` class.

So i have basically two Questions:

1. for what is this 'name' property intended
2. is it safe to overwrite it with a `settattr` assignment?

The example-code for completness:

```
class MockFile(StringIO): 
    def __init__(self, name, buffer_ = None):
        super(MockFile, self).__init__(buffer_)
        self.name = name     
>>> mfile = MockFile('stringio.tmp', u'#MockFile')
```

leads to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` property of `io.StringIO` in Python 2.6 comes from the class hierarchy in the `io` module. It's a somewhat complex setup with both inheritance and composition, and the `name` property is used to propagate names from underlying objects to the various wrappers and specializations. The actual property on `io.StringIO` is gone in Python 2.7 and later, though, so you should be fine to shadow it in your subclass.

You can't use `setattr()` to set the property any more than actual assignment -- `settattr()` and attribute assignment both work the same way. The nature of property prevents you from shadowing the baseclass property with an instance attribute (without doing more.) You can, however, define a property of your own with the same name, or trick Python into not seeing the property in the first place:

```
class MockFile(StringIO):
    name = None
    def __init__(self, name, buffer_ = None):
        super(MockFile, self).__init__(buffer_)
        self.name = name
```

Comment: Just for the record, the trick of shadowing a property with an instance attribute doesn't work in all cases (it doesn't work for properties that have a setter.)